# How to dispatch this url in Python?

Tags: python, regex, django, web

I want to dispatch a url of type: ***/algorithms/algorithm_name/topic/***

I am working in Django 2.0.1. This is what I tried:

```
    url(r'^(?P<topic_name>[a-zA-Z a-zA-Z a-zA-Z]+)/$',views.topic,name='topic'),
```

How to write the regex pattern for my url type?

Comment: Is `algorithms`, etc. fixed, or is this a slug as well?

Comment: algorithms is fixed.algorithm_name and topic are a slug

Comment: In the pattern this part `[a-zA-Z a-zA-Z a-zA-Z]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with ranges a-zA-Z and a space. It could be shortened to `[a-zA-Z ]` If you only want to match the topic name (without taking the structure of the url into account) you could omit the `^` anchor  `(?P<topic_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$` https://regex101.com/r/lbIhWp/1

Comment: Please don't create multiple new accounts. You are the same person as https://stackoverflow.com/users/11702971/darshan-chheda, please use that account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you can make use of [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path), which is more readable with [*path converters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). A path converter can be seen as a named URL pattern that can also (process the captured URL part into some other object).

You could define a path like:

```
path(
    'algorithms/<slug:algorithm_name>/<slug:topic_name>/',
    views.topic,
    name='topic'
),
```

Your `topic` function thus has two extra parameters, like:

```
# app/views.py

def topic(request, algorithm_name, topic_name):
     # ...
```